# Vue Material - MdTable initialization error in data fetching

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-material

As I stated [here](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/1870), I'm trying to fetching remote data to initialize `MdTable` component, but the process throws a `null` error. Data being fetched from a *MySQL* DB, part of a *Laravel 5.6* API project.

After a deep analysis, I assumed that the issue is caused by a premature initialization of component itself, before the finish of fetching process. So, the model that manage component data results empty, and rendering crashes.

I tried different ways: the navigation is managed by *Vue-Router*, so both [Before/After Navigation data fetching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation) techniques has been tested, and the result is the same. Using props from parent component, as well as defining component navigation guards, seems to be useless in order to avoid the problem.

I think the solution could be to hold the component rendering until data being fetched. But I really don't get how. I tried with `beforeCreate()/created()` too, but none of them helped.

I'm stuck from many days in this situation, some help or suggestion to try at last a new direction is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As I stated here](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/1870), Due to a syntax error on my implementation:

```
[...]
<md-table-cell v-for="(val, i) in item" :key="val.id" v-if="(i !== 'id') && (i !== 
'estensione_garanzia') && (i !== 'note')"
[...]
```

The attribute `:key="val.id"` is misconfigured. In this case I'm iterating an array of objects - without nested of them - so there's no sub-property `id` on selected element. For more information the [official doc](https://vuematerial.io/components/tabs) shows a complete example

By changing the attribute like this:

```
:key="val.id"
```

Everything works fine.